# What are the functions of the Assembly x86 EDI, SIL, and DL registers?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
lk:
movl %edi , %r9d
jmp .L8

L8:
movzbl %sil , %eax
movzbl %dl , %ecx
leal -1(%rcx) , %r8d
cmpl %r8d, %eax
jl .L4 //if (%eax <%r8d) goto .L4
cltq // extend %eax int %rax
movl %esi, %eax
cmovle %edx, %eax // if (ecran(%rax)<=%dil) %eax=%edx
ret

main:
...
movzbl %bl,%eax
movsbl clavier(%rax), %ebp
movsbl le(%rip),%edx
movl $0, %esi
movl %ebl, %edi
call lk
movzbl %al, %esi
...
ret
```

What do `%edi` and `%sil` and `%dl` represent in the function `lk` and what are their types?

Comment: Presumably the C function signature is `lk(uint32_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)`, using the x86-64 System V calling convention.  Args are passed in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, ...

Answer (score 6):

`edi` is a register, a general purpose one which is generally used to hold the destination for string operations (`scas` etc.)
But as any other general purpose register, can be used to hold any other data.

In general, forget about "types" in assembly: assembly is not a typed language, or better any data is just bytes. They can have different sizes, but that's all: a register can hold any x-bits (32 bits, in this case, or 4 bytes) data, and you cannot tell if it is a bunch of chars, an integer, or a pointer.

(I assume you are using a GNU assembler; in that case, %something is almost always a register)

Oh, and you have different names for different *portions* of a register: so for example `%dl` is the lower 8 bits of the "d" register (`edx` on 32 bit machines, `rdx` on 64 bits) register, and `%sil` represent the lower 8 bits of the `esi` register.

You can find all this information in the excellent Intel assembly manuals. 
There is a LOT to study on the subject before becoming proficient. At least, you should start [reading wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language). Then, I suggest you look at some tutorial, read the Intel manuals, [study calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), ...

Comment: for exemple what is the type of variables ecran and clavier her :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209662/assembly-variables-type-to-langage-c

Comment: what does the register %eax do at the end of of the function lk and what is the C prototype of the lk function

Comment: Do not open two questions on the same subject.. it actually reduces your change of getting a complete answer. You can edit your question if you need to add details, see the FAQ

Comment: I repeat: assembly is not a typed language (at least, not x86 assembly). As suggested in the other answer, they might be platform specific extensions/something in the context that lets you access the screen, keyboard, etc.

Comment: Also, it is not possible to tell what could be the C prototype of lk (which is NOT a function, it's just a label: it does not have a standard prologue/epilogue)

Comment: Same job as for all register: hold data. A register does not _do_ anything, it just holds some bytes (32, in the case of %eax). 
If this assembly is compiled C code (which I highly doubt it is) it _could_ hold the return value for a function. See my edited answer and follow the "calling conventions" link

Comment: ?? "assembly is not a typed language" --> "there is no type". Asking what is the type is like asking which kind of wings a dog have... (a dog has NO wings)

Comment: but in the prgoramme they represente a string? the type of the fonction LK

Comment: They could. It is not possible to tell from a small fragment; besides, now you have a basic explanations and a bunch of pointers where you can go and start learning and understanding. You really need to read if you want to understand assembly. Good luck!

Comment: "the type of the function LK" 1) "LK" is not a function 2) _there is NO such a thing as a type in assembly_ Asking again and again will not give you a different answer...

Comment: now you have the full code you can tell me the type o f ecran clavier and le variables

Comment: ...this must be a joke... 
I surrender -_-